# Are there any (FOSS) projects which encapsulate scribe-java for use as a JSON web service?

Tags: oauth, scribe

I want to use encapsulate scribe in a REST web service, which I can easily do, but don't want to go down that that path if someone has already done it. The idea is, I would use scribe-java with JAX-RS to allow my other (internal, SaaS env) apps to use OAuth by calling a particular (internal) URL, and the service would respond appropriately with JSON.

I only need authentication at this point. For that matter, the solution doesn't necessarily have to be based on scribe-java ... I just want to authenticate using OAuth over REST, rather than through a Java library, that way I have a language neutral solution.

I like what scribe-java provides, but I want it via REST instead. I'll even settle for SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate an educational, example project here. It also uses OpenID + Oauth for Yahoo instead of pure OAuth which does not provide the Yahoo email: https://github.com/sylnsr/scribe-java-ws